# Inserting newline between matched text is overwriting

Tags: perl

I have a text file. I am trying to search for a comma followed by a date, like ",08/18/2014".

It looks like my code finds it, but it replaces it with a comma and a new line and removes everything after it.

```
 if ($firstline =~ s|\,(\d{2}\/.*)|\,\n|g){
     print "$firstline";
```

How do I add a new line between the comma and the date and not remove my text and date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference your capture groups in your replace expression. I also expanded the regular expression to match the date exactly:

```
if ($firstline =~ s|,(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})|,\n$1|g) {
   print "$firstline\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 because this is "understand-able" for an beginner too... :)

Comment: Thanks. Seems really easy, add the $1.

Comment: Except that the OP has a slash after the first field of the date, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Using look ahead/behind:

```
s|(?<=,)(?=\d{2}\/)|\n|g
```

or

```
s|,\K(?=\d{2}\/)|\n|g     # Probably faster, but requires 5.10+
```

Comment: Going to study `perlre`... I hope will understand this somedays.. ;)

Comment: Wow, even shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Hunter's answer, without the extended regex, like so:

(Oh, and I don't think you need the backslash before the comma):

```
$firstline = "hello world ,10/20/1987, sounds great to me";  # testing...

if ($firstline =~ s|,(\d{2}/)|,\n$1|g){
     print "$firstline";
}
```

output:

```
hello world ,
10/20/1987, sounds great to me
```

Comment: Re `\1 works the same as $1`: [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1)

Comment: Agreed.  I shouldn't've gotten cute with it.

Comment: @rje You can edit your answer at any time to improve it. Just click the "edit" button at the bottom.